# Structures with strings and input

Tags: c, string, input, structure

I have the following structure and function that adds things to the structure:

```
struct scoreentry_node {
    struct scoreentry_node *next;
    int score;
    char* name;    
}
;

typedef struct scoreentry_node *score_entry;

score_entry add(int in, char* n, score_entry en) {      
   score_entry r = malloc(sizeof(struct scoreentry_node));
   r->score = in;
   r->name = n;
   r->next = en;  
   return r;   
}
```

i have input that take it in the following main file:

```
int score;
char name[];

int main(void) {
score_entry readin = NULL;

while(1)
{

        scanf("%s%d", name, &score);
        readin = add(score, name, readin);
       // blah blah
```

I dont know why but when input a name it gets added to `readin`, but when i input another name all the names in `readin` have this new name

for example:

```
input:
bob 10 
readin = 10 bob NULL

jill 20
readin = 20 jill 10 jill NULL
```

I dont know why bob disappears... any reason why it does that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just storing a pointer to the name string, not a copy of the string itself. Try using `strdup`:

```
r->name = strdup(n);
```

Just be sure to `free(r->name)` when freeing a node.

An alternative would be to change `char* name` to `char name[1]`, and do something like this:

```
score_entry add(int in, char* n, score_entry en) {      
   score_entry r = malloc(sizeof(struct scoreentry_node) + strlen(n));
   r->score = in;
   strcpy(r->name, n);

   [..]
```

This saves allocating a separate chunk of memory for the string, but note that in that case `name` *must* be at the end of your structure.

Comment: im going with changing `char* name` to `char name[1]` in the struct im getting a compiler error in my function add ` incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[1]’ from type ‘char *’` ... where exactly would i add 'strlen(name)' ?